# Como adiciono os elementos de um List<string> para um listBox?

Tags: c#, lista

Tenho um List numa classe, e na classe principal eu quero pegar esse List e adicionar seus elementos num listBox e depois exibi-los. Como faço isso?Obrigado!!

Comment: Poste o que já fez e qual é sua dificuldade.

Comment: Olá, amigo. A dificuldade é que sou iniciante em C#. Pesquisei sobre listas em C#, encontrei e aprendi como usá-las, agora queria exibir seu conteúdo e quero fazer isso num componente listBox, e não sei como. Então, o que já fiz até agora, foi preencher essa lista. Somente isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis a resposta, a quem tiver dúvida semelhante:

```
foreach (var p in obterPares.pares)

    {
         listBoxParesGerados.Items.Add(p);
    }
```

O p no foreach percorrerá cada elemento da lista, então, usando o Add do listBox, adicione p

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a propriedade [DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx).

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>();
lista.Add("Nome 1");
lista.Add("Nome 2");
lista.Add("Nome 3");
listBox.DataSource = lista;
```